# How can I calculate font size for my UILabel?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel, uifont

I have a `UILabel` measuring 984x728 px with variable text. How can I calculate the maximum font size to fit the `UILabel`?

Comment: use  [lable setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a font larger than you would ever want (48 points is probably good). Then use this:

```
CGFloat maxFontSize;
[string sizeWithFont:font minFontSize:0 actualFontSize:&maxFontSize forWidth:maxWidth lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeClip];
```

`maxFontSize` will hold the largest size less than 48 and greater than 0 that will fit within `maxWidth`.

Comment: The API Rob mentions `sizeWithFont:` has been deprecated in iOS7. Please see this Stack Overflow question for a more complete response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897896/replacement-for-deprecated-sizewithfont-in-ios-7